# Ubuntu 18.04 Anaconda 3 desktop shortcut does not launch application properly

Tags: desktop-application, ubuntu-18.04, anaconda3

Hello Im new to Ubuntu/programming forgive me for a potentially stupid mistake.
I successfully downloaded and installed Anaconda3 on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 and confirmed it launches in the terminal.
Then I wanted to create a desktop application for it and looked online for a tutorial. I used the code below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Navigator
GenericName=Anaconda
Comment=Scientific Python Development Environment - Python3
Exec=bash -c 'export PATH="/home/Roland/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" && /home/Roland/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator'
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;Education;
Icon=/home/Roland/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-python;
```

I placed this in /usr/share/applications with the filename Anaconda.desktop.

It shows up in my app menu but the icon does not work for one. When I try and launch it the top left in Ubuntu which shows the name of the current open application will say anaconda navigator and the cursor icon changes to loading. But the anaconda logo never comes up and the app never launches.

Answer (score 0):

So the error was:
1. Username shouldn't have been capitalised
2. The file should be sitting in the Home directory and /.local/share/applications

Now it works!